# openload.cc How can I extract encoding settings of videos?

Tags: video, encoding, settings

openload.cc How can I find encoding settings of output videos?
My customer needs streaming service for his IP cameras and he ask me about same output quality as videos in openload.cc but I can´t simulate similar quality.I tried several encoding combination but nothing works fine.

My client needs reduce quality/size with good visibility in output
I ask my client about choice which online service has good visibility for him and he choose openload.cc

So I need find encoding settings now.

Comment: Use a tool like **MediaInfo**. You need to save a video from openload.cc and drag to your running MediaInfo tool and it shows you format settings (maybe that will help you).

Comment: I don´t know how to download video from openload.cc

Comment: This is a programming forum. I would assume the first place anyone checks is within the HTML source code of the video page. Anyways I suggest you try asking on the [**Video**](http://video.stackexchange.com/) forum instead. When asking there... you can improve your question by showing a screen grab of expected picture quality (a site video). Show your own settings you tried (and name of program you used). Show also a screen grab of what result(s) you get from your encoder settings. **MediaInfo** is the more popular tool for showing encoder settings as per your question...